# Problem with loading pretrained Universal Sentence Encoder

Tags: python, tensorflow, nlp, tensorflow2.0, pre-trained-model

I have a problem with loading pretrained module for an NLP task and the problem is because of the tf migration I suppose. Tensorflow website says that the problem might be sorted if the signature variable is given correctly. Can you help me correct this code ?

TypeError: 'AutoTrackable' object is not callable

[code]

```
import tensorflow_hub as hub
# enabling the pretrained model for trainig our custom model using tensorflow hub
module_url = "https://tfhub.dev/google/universal-sentence-encoder-large/3"
embed = hub.load(module_url)

# creating a method for embedding and will using method for every input layer 
def UniversalEmbedding(x):
    return embed(tf.squeeze(tf.cast(x, tf.string)), signature='default', as_dict=True)["default"]
```

Comment: I was able to run this in Google Colab without any error and also ran fine in both the versions of tensorflow -  %tensorflow_version 1.x and %tensorflow_version 2.x. Which IDE you are using? And the tensorflow version?

Answer (score 1):

I am new in this field but I can share with you what I did to fix my problem:

- Check your Tensorflow version using this command:

  print(tensorflow.**version**)
- You can change Tensorflow version by running the below code before running import tensorflow

%tensorflow_version 1.x

- My TF version is 1.x, and I was using `hub.load(url)` and was getting 'Auto Trackable' error message, when I replaced it with `hub.Module(url)` it fixed my problem
- You might find these links helpful! In case you don't know about them

https://tfhub.dev/google/elmo/3
https://www.tensorflow.org/hub/common_issues

Best of luck